# Logging in multithreaded env

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, executorservice

I am logging(in separate file) about some records after processing them in multi-threaded environment.
Log has to be in certain format(Header, columns ..) like below
[image]

Currently, I am checking No==1 and logging header. Since it is multithreaded env, Order of the no is not the same everytime. 
Please suggest me a way to achieve this.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure what your question is about How are you logging and what? What does MT has to do anything with logging? Ideally loggers are "First come first serve". You need to produce a sequential output to the logger.

Comment: @Prashant  I am logging like it is given in the picture. I need to log the header first- since it is MT, header is being logged somewhere in between. I want to log the header first.

Comment: The logging aspect is basically irrelevant. This is a multithreaded task, so you need to generate your data, collect the results, and _then_ log them.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I dont mind if other data is not in order, I just want header to be printed first.

Comment: Why not collect data until head is found and then simply dump that out?

Comment: @Prashant Almost 10k+ records,  design prefers logging as it comes.

Comment: So then you could generate the header either before the task starts, or after it's finished.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchneider that's helpful, If you could post it as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for no==1, I decided to check for the flag and disable it after printing header.

Thanks for comments and suggestions.